# Resizing the text in the section

Tags: fontsize

I am trying to develop some lecture notes. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\Large#1\end{center}
   }%
}



\newcommand{\subsubtitle}[1]{%
  \preauthor{%
    \begin{center}
    \large #1 \vskip0.5em
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    }%
}


\title{Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics }
\subtitle{Lecture 1}
\subsubtitle{Basics of Manifolds}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.0cm}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Why Symplectic Geometry?}

It is a mathematical formalism underlying
\begin{itemize}
\item Geometrical Optics  
\item Classical Mechanics
\item General Relativity
\item Quantum Mechanics
\end{itemize}

Such a unifying formalism help us to solve problems in one area of physics
by using ideas from another areas.
It doesn't work for systems with loss, friction or noise.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The size of the text "Why Symplectic Geometry?" is too big? Can I reduce its size? Also there is too much white space between the border of the page and the starting point of text on either side. Is there a way to increase the width of the each and every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you can use `titlesec` in its simplified `\titleformat*`  command.

As to the margins, you can choose their values with package `geometry`. Here is a possibility, to be adapted to your needs. I took the liberty to simplify the code for the `\subtitle` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin =2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\vskip\topsep
    \Large#1\end{center}
   }%
}



\newcommand{\subsubtitle}[1]{%
  \preauthor{%
    \begin{center}
    \large #1 \vskip0.5em
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    }%
}


\title{Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics }
\subtitle{Lecture 1}
\subsubtitle{Basics of Manifolds}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.0cm}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Why Symplectic Geometry?}

It is a mathematical formalism underlying
\begin{itemize}
\item Geometrical Optics
\item Classical Mechanics
\item General Relativity
\item Quantum Mechanics
\end{itemize}

Such a unifying formalism help us to solve problems in one area of physics
by using ideas from another areas.
It doesn't work for systems with loss, friction or noise.

\end{document}
```

[image]